# How to resolve the fatal error "EXCEPTION_ACCES_VIOLATION" with "Failed to write core dump."

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I would like to create a window in a thread I created before, on ItelliJ IDEA if it can help.
Actually I'm following [this youtube guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=527bR2JHSR0) (until 22:55).

The complete error is the following :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005d283b6f, pid=5112, tid=9000
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x1d3b6f]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000167f1000):  JavaThread "Game" [_thread_in_vm, id=9000, stack(0x0000000016df0000,0x0000000016ef0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000780

Registers:
RAX=0x00000000167f1000, RBX=0x00000000167f1000, RCX=0x000000000000001f, RDX=0x0000000016eef018
RSP=0x0000000016eeef40, RBP=0x0000000016eeefe8, RSI=0x0000000000200021, RDI=0x0000000000000780
R8 =0x0000000000000780, R9 =0x00000000eb4bdad0, R10=0x0000000002895b48, R11=0x000000005d2c2810
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000000001456a938, R14=0x0000000016eef018, R15=0x00000000167f1000
RIP=0x000000005d283b6f, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000016eeef40)
0x0000000016eeef40:   0000000016eef088 00000000148f2c80
0x0000000016eeef50:   0000000014956868 00000000167f1000
0x0000000016eeef60:   0000000002887470 0000000002895b74
0x0000000016eeef70:   000000001456a938 0000000016eeefe8
0x0000000016eeef80:   0000000000200021 00000000148f2028
0x0000000016eeef90:   00000000000000b8 00000000167f1000
0x0000000016eeefa0:   0000000000000000 0000000016eeefa8
0x0000000016eeefb0:   0000000000000000 0000000016eef018
0x0000000016eeefc0:   00000000145859c0 0000000000000000
0x0000000016eeefd0:   000000001456a938 0000000000000000
0x0000000016eeefe0:   0000000016eef008 0000000016eef060
0x0000000016eeeff0:   0000000002887470 0000000000000000
0x0000000016eef000:   000000000288f6b6 0000000000000780
0x0000000016eef010:   0000000000000000 00000000eb18d698
0x0000000016eef020:   0000000016eef020 000000001492eb24
0x0000000016eef030:   0000000016eef080 0000000014932248 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000005d283b6f)
0x000000005d283b4f:   4a 05 00 c7 83 60 02 00 00 06 00 00 00 8b 0d d6
0x000000005d283b5f:   a1 5a 00 ff 15 80 08 3e 00 c6 80 84 02 00 00 01
0x000000005d283b6f:   8b 2f c6 80 84 02 00 00 00 48 8b 7b 48 48 8b 47
0x000000005d283b7f:   10 48 8b 77 08 48 83 38 00 74 15 48 8b 57 28 48 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00000000167f1000 is a thread
RBX=0x00000000167f1000 is a thread
RCX=0x000000000000001f is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000016eef018 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000167f1000
RSP=0x0000000016eeef40 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000167f1000
RBP=0x0000000016eeefe8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000167f1000
RSI=0x0000000000200021 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000780 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000780 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00000000eb4bdad0 is an oop
java.lang.Class 
 - klass: 'java/lang/Class'
R10=0x0000000002895b48 is at code_begin+840 in an Interpreter codelet
method entry point (kind = native)  [0x0000000002895800, 0x0000000002896160]  2400 bytes
R11=0x000000005d2c2810 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13={method} {0x000000001456a940} 'getInt' '(J)I' in 'sun/misc/Unsafe'
R14=0x0000000016eef018 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000167f1000
R15=0x00000000167f1000 is a thread


Stack: [0x0000000016df0000,0x0000000016ef0000],  sp=0x0000000016eeef40,  free space=1019k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x1d3b6f]
C  0x0000000002895b74

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.misc.Unsafe.getInt(J)I+0
j  org.lwjgl.system.MemoryAccess$MemoryAccessorUnsafe.memGetInt(J)I+4
j  org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.memGetInt(J)I+4
j  org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode.nwidth(J)I+6
j  Main.init()V+59
j  Main.run()V+1
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00000000026ee000 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=1336, stack(0x00000000025a0000,0x00000000026a0000)]
=>0x00000000167f1000 JavaThread "Game" [_thread_in_vm, id=9000, stack(0x0000000016df0000,0x0000000016ef0000)]
  0x00000000167d9800 JavaThread "Monitor Ctrl-Break" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3672, stack(0x0000000016cf0000,0x0000000016df0000)]
  0x0000000014eed800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10028, stack(0x0000000016af0000,0x0000000016bf0000)]
  0x0000000014e98000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7928, stack(0x00000000165f0000,0x00000000166f0000)]
  0x0000000014e91800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10196, stack(0x00000000164f0000,0x00000000165f0000)]
  0x0000000014e8e800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5496, stack(0x00000000163f0000,0x00000000164f0000)]
  0x0000000014e8d000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4916, stack(0x00000000162f0000,0x00000000163f0000)]
  0x0000000014e8c000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7920, stack(0x00000000161f0000,0x00000000162f0000)]
  0x0000000002876800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9636, stack(0x00000000160f0000,0x00000000161f0000)]
  0x0000000014e58800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7608, stack(0x0000000015ff0000,0x00000000160f0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000014e57000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000015ef0000,0x0000000015ff0000] [id=8024]
  0x0000000016708000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000016bf0000,0x0000000016cf0000] [id=9784]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 18944K, used 3933K [0x00000000eb180000, 0x00000000ec680000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 16384K, 24% used [0x00000000eb180000,0x00000000eb557448,0x00000000ec180000)
  from space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ec400000,0x00000000ec400000,0x00000000ec680000)
  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ec180000,0x00000000ec180000,0x00000000ec400000)
 ParOldGen       total 44032K, used 0K [0x00000000c1400000, 0x00000000c3f00000, 0x00000000eb180000)
  object space 44032K, 0% used [0x00000000c1400000,0x00000000c1400000,0x00000000c3f00000)
 Metaspace       used 3894K, capacity 4984K, committed 5120K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 414K, capacity 424K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011c40000,0x0000000011e40000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000011636000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000005d88d490
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012390000, 0x0000000013340000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000013340000, 0x00000000142f0000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000db0000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=1445Kb max_used=1458Kb free=244314Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002880000, 0x0000000002af0000, 0x0000000011880000]
 total_blobs=586 nmethods=151 adapters=349
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.362 Thread 0x0000000014e98000 nmethod 144 0x00000000029e6c90 code [0x00000000029e6e20, 0x00000000029e7198]
Event: 0.471 Thread 0x0000000014e98000  146       3       java.lang.String::<init> (10 bytes)
Event: 0.472 Thread 0x0000000014e98000 nmethod 146 0x00000000029e7690 code [0x00000000029e77e0, 0x00000000029e79b0]
Event: 0.472 Thread 0x0000000014e98000  147       1       sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader::access$500 (5 bytes)
Event: 0.472 Thread 0x0000000014e98000 nmethod 147 0x00000000029e7a50 code [0x00000000029e7ba0, 0x00000000029e7c90]
Event: 0.472 Thread 0x0000000014e98000  148       3       java.util.zip.Inflater::ensureOpen (47 bytes)
Event: 0.473 Thread 0x0000000014e98000 nmethod 148 0x00000000029e7d10 code [0x00000000029e7e80, 0x00000000029e8148]
Event: 0.473 Thread 0x0000000014e98000  149  s    3       sun.misc.PerfCounter::add (18 bytes)
Event: 0.473 Thread 0x0000000014e98000 nmethod 149 0x00000000029e8250 code [0x00000000029e83e0, 0x00000000029e8a58]
Event: 0.475 Thread 0x0000000014e91800  151       4       sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder::encode (359 bytes)

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.329 Thread 0x00000000167f1000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb5059a8) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 0.329 Thread 0x00000000167f1000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb50a1d0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 0.330 Thread 0x00000000167f1000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb50df98) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 0.335 Thread 0x00000000167f1000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb51af40) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 0.362 Thread 0x00000000167f1000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb5266c0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 0.470 Thread 0x00000000167f1000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb52abd0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 0.471 Thread 0x00000000167f1000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb530608) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 0.473 Thread 0x00000000167f1000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb536120) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 0.474 Thread 0x00000000167f1000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb53a420) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 0.475 Thread 0x00000000167f1000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb53dd50) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.470 loading class org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFWVidMode
Event: 0.470 loading class org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFWVidMode done
Event: 0.471 loading class org/lwjgl/system/Struct
Event: 0.471 loading class org/lwjgl/system/Struct done
Event: 0.473 loading class org/lwjgl/system/PointerWrapper
Event: 0.473 loading class org/lwjgl/system/PointerWrapper done
Event: 0.474 loading class org/lwjgl/system/Struct$Member
Event: 0.474 loading class org/lwjgl/system/Struct$Member done
Event: 0.475 loading class org/lwjgl/system/Struct$Layout
Event: 0.475 loading class org/lwjgl/system/Struct$Layout done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff6fe530000 - 0x00007ff6fe564000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe
0x00007ff90cd00000 - 0x00007ff90ceac000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ff90a6a0000 - 0x00007ff90a7de000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ff90a020000 - 0x00007ff90a135000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ff9089f0000 - 0x00007ff908a7e000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x00007ff8f1200000 - 0x00007ff8f1253000     C:\Windows\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcGenral.DLL
0x00007ff90cb00000 - 0x00007ff90cbaa000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ff909cf0000 - 0x00007ff909d1e000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
0x00007ff90a5d0000 - 0x00007ff90a624000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x00007ff90aa00000 - 0x00007ff90ab77000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x00007ff90ae30000 - 0x00007ff90afc4000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x00007ff90afe0000 - 0x00007ff90c50b000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ff909450000 - 0x00007ff909471000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x00007ff90c530000 - 0x00007ff90c5da000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ff8f8f10000 - 0x00007ff8f8f2e000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
0x00007ff90a3e0000 - 0x00007ff90a521000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ff90a630000 - 0x00007ff90a689000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x00007ff90a7e0000 - 0x00007ff90a9f1000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
0x00007ff90cbb0000 - 0x00007ff90ccff000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ff909e50000 - 0x00007ff909e65000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
0x00007ff9083a0000 - 0x00007ff908452000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHCORE.dll
0x00007ff90a590000 - 0x00007ff90a5c6000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007ff90c7d0000 - 0x00007ff90c922000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007ff907f20000 - 0x00007ff90819b000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.18006_none_623f33d3ecbe86e8\COMCTL32.dll
0x000000005d910000 - 0x000000005d9e2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x000000005d0b0000 - 0x000000005d90a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ff8ff6b0000 - 0x00007ff8ff6b9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ff9079c0000 - 0x00007ff9079e2000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ff90afd0000 - 0x00007ff90afd7000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ff90a380000 - 0x00007ff90a3da000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ff9078c0000 - 0x00007ff9078ea000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ff90c510000 - 0x00007ff90c519000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x00007ff909f20000 - 0x00007ff909f6f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x00007ff908c40000 - 0x00007ff908c68000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x000000005e8b0000 - 0x000000005e8bf000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x000000005d080000 - 0x000000005d0a8000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\java.dll
0x000000005d060000 - 0x000000005d076000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ff9088d0000 - 0x00007ff9088e0000     F:\Logiciels\IntelliJ IDEA\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.5\bin\breakgen64.dll
0x000000005d040000 - 0x000000005d05a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\net.dll
0x00007ff909830000 - 0x00007ff909889000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x00007ff8ea5c0000 - 0x00007ff8ea648000     F:\Logiciels\Eclipse\Workspace\Duju\native\lwjgl.dll
0x00007ff909d90000 - 0x00007ff909d9b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.DLL
0x00007ff909d20000 - 0x00007ff909d83000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ff8ea2e0000 - 0x00007ff8ea322000     F:\Logiciels\Eclipse\Workspace\Duju\native\jemalloc.dll
0x00007ff8ee6a0000 - 0x00007ff8ee6d8000     F:\Logiciels\Eclipse\Workspace\Duju\native\glfw.dll
0x00007ff908ac0000 - 0x00007ff908be9000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x00007ff9081a0000 - 0x00007ff9081c1000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
0x00007ff8ee200000 - 0x00007ff8ee32b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\opengl32.dll
0x00007ff8f6090000 - 0x00007ff8f60be000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll
0x00007ff8ecc80000 - 0x00007ff8ecd78000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DDRAW.dll
0x00007ff906fa0000 - 0x00007ff906fa9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x00007ff8d6ea0000 - 0x00007ff8d77cd000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ig75icd64.dll
0x00007ff8eeae0000 - 0x00007ff8ef4bd000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\igdusc64.dll
0x00007ff9089d0000 - 0x00007ff9089e2000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll
0x00007ff9094d0000 - 0x00007ff909516000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\powrprof.dll
0x00007ff908cb0000 - 0x00007ff908cbb000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ff8f9c20000 - 0x00007ff8f9da9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.library.path=native/ -Didea.launcher.port=7536 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=F:\Logiciels\IntelliJ IDEA\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.5\bin -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 
java_command: com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Main
java_class_path (initial): C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;F:\Logiciels\Eclipse\Workspace\Duju\out\production\Duju;F:\Logiciels\Eclipse\Workspace\Duju\jar\lwjgl.jar;F:\Logiciels\IntelliJ IDEA\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.5\lib\idea_rt.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
PATH=F:\Logiciels\OCaml\emacs-23.3\bin;F:\Logiciels\OCaml\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
USERNAME=Alex
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 8.1 , 64 bit Build 9600 

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 60 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2

Memory: 4k page, physical 4110944k(899212k free), swap 8305248k(2328032k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_25-b18), built on Oct  7 2014 14:25:37 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Wed Dec 02 20:49:40 2015
elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)
```

I tried everything I saw in the similar posts : I've uninstalled/reinstalled java, changed the project/workspace folder, disabled the windows UAC...

Here is my code :

```
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_TRUE;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.NULL;

/**
 * Created by Alex on 02/12/2015.
 */
public class Main implements Runnable{

    //Taille de la fenetre
    private int width = 1280;
    private int height = 720;

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;

    private long window;


    public void start() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this, "Game");
        thread.start();




        /*glfwInit();

        createCapabilities(); // Links LWJGL to the OpenGL context

        // Enter the update loop: keep refreshing the window as long as the window isn't closed
        while (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_FALSE) {
            // Clear the contents of the window (try disabling this and resizing the window – fun guaranteed)
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            glfwPollEvents();
        }

        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        glfwTerminate();*/



    }

    private void init() {
        if(glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) {
            //TODO : gerer ce cas ou l'initialisation du GLFW a plante.
            return;
        }

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);
        // Configuration de la fenetre
        window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Duju", NULL, NULL);

        if (window == NULL) {
            //TODO : gerer le cas ou la fenetre est nulle.
            return;
        }

        //Pour placer la fenetre au centre, on get le video mode
        GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        //Set la position
        glfwSetWindowPos(window, GLFWVidMode.nwidth(vidmode.width()) /2, GLFWVidMode.nheight(vidmode.height()) /2);
        //Si on a des objets, on la set comme ca
        //window.setPos(xpos,ypos);
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwSwapInterval(1); // VSync pour caper a 60fps
        glfwShowWindow(window);


    }

    //Lance quand le thread est cree
    public void run() {
        init();
        while (running) {
            update();
            render();

            if (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_TRUE)
                running = false;
        }
    }

    private void update() {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    private void render() {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try updating your Java? You are using JDK 8 u 25, the latest one is 8 u 66: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: I just did it but it doesn't change anything.
Thank you anyway.

Comment: I don't know anything about the glfw library you are using, but it is crashing on the call to GLFWVidMode.nwidth(...), possibly trying to retrieve an Int value from the vidmode() object, according to the java frames listed in the error messages.  Are you sure vidmode is being initialized properly?  Again, I don't know anything about this library, just a guess.

Comment: May be try to take a look at this [link](http://www.java-forums.org/eclipse/312-exception_access_violation-0xc0000005.html)

Comment: The Javadoc of [GLFWVidMode#nwidth()](http://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFWVidMode.html#nwidth(long)) which you are using and which crashes, says "Unsafe version of GLFWVidMode.width().". In the stacktrace in the crash you see that it indeed goes to `sun.misc.Unsafe.getInt()`. It seems you are yourself responsible for passing in a "safe" parameter value. Can you use the safe `.width()` method instead?

Comment: Yes ! It works !
Indeed, I used `.width()` like this : `glfwSetWindowPos(window, vidmode.width() /2, vidmode.height()/2);` and well, it worked !
Thank you everyone for your help !

Comment: @Alex, please answer your own question or delete the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I used the safe `.width()` like this : `glfwSetWindowPos(window, vidmode.width() /2, vidmode.height()/2);`. It worked well.